# how to parse a dicomfile that is stored locally in our system and display the image corresponding to that dcm file using cornerstone library

Tags: javascript, html

i have DCM files which are stored locally in my system. I need to get that file by browsing it and then want to parse that DCM file to find the values of rescale slope(0028,1053) and rescale intercept(0028,1052) etc . And need to display DCM image corresponding to that DCM file. I have included the decomposer library and cornerstone library in my HTML page using script tags. I am a beginner in javascript world.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <!-- <link href="../cornerstone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">



    <div id="loadProgress">Image Load Progress:</div>

    <div class="row">
        <form id="form" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="file" id="selectFile" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="width:512px;height:512px;position:relative;color: white;display:inline-block;border-style:solid;border-color:black;"
                 oncontextmenu="return false"
                 class='disable-selection noIbar'
                 unselectable='on'
                 onselectstart='return false;'
                 onmousedown='return false;'>
                <div id="dicomImage"
                     style="width:512px;height:512px;top:0px;left:0px; position:absolute">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <span>Transfer Syntax: </span><span id="transferSyntax"></span><br>
            <span>SOP Class: </span><span id="sopClass"></span><br>
            <span>Samples Per Pixel: </span><span id="samplesPerPixel"></span><br>
            <span>Photometric Interpretation: </span><span id="photometricInterpretation"></span><br>
            <span>Number Of Frames: </span><span id="numberOfFrames"></span><br>
            <span>Planar Configuration: </span><span id="planarConfiguration"></span><br>
            <span>Rows: </span><span id="rows"></span><br>
            <span>Columns: </span><span id="columns"></span><br>
            <span>Pixel Spacing: </span><span id="pixelSpacing"></span><br>
            <span>Bits Allocated: </span><span id="bitsAllocated"></span><br>
            <span>Bits Stored: </span><span id="bitsStored"></span><br>
            <span>High Bit: </span><span id="highBit"></span><br>
            <span>Pixel Representation: </span><span id="pixelRepresentation"></span><br>
            <span>WindowCenter: </span><span id="windowCenter"></span><br>
            <span>WindowWidth: </span><span id="windowWidth"></span><br>
            <span>RescaleIntercept: </span><span id="rescaleIntercept"></span><br>
            <span>RescaleSlope: </span><span id="rescaleSlope"></span><br>
            <span>Basic Offset Table Entries: </span><span id="basicOffsetTable"></span><br>
            <span>Fragments: </span><span id="fragments"></span><br>
            <span>Min Stored Pixel Value: </span><span id="minStoredPixelValue"></span><br>
            <span>Max Stored Pixel Value: </span><span id="maxStoredPixelValue"></span><br>
            <span>Total Time: </span><span id="totalTime"></span><br>
            <span>Load Time: </span><span id="loadTime"></span><br>
            <span>Decode Time: </span><span id="decodeTime"></span><br>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cornerstone-math@0.1.6/dist/cornerstoneMath.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cornerstone-core@2.2.4/dist/cornerstone.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cornerstone-web-image-loader@2.1.0/dist/cornerstoneWebImageLoader.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cornerstone-tools@next" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cornerstone-tools@3.0.0-b.641/dist/cornerstoneTools.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/dicom-parser@1.8.3/dist/dicomParser.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/dicom-parser@1.8.3/dist/dicomParser.min.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cornerstone-wado-image-loader@2.2.3/dist/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.min.js" async defer></script>


<script>
    cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone;


    // this function gets called once the user drops the file onto the div
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

        // Get the FileList object that contains the list of files that were dropped
        const files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

        // this UI is only built for a single file so just dump the first one
        file = files[0];
        const imageId = cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.wadouri.fileManager.add(file);
        loadAndViewImage(imageId);
    }

    function handleDragOver(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
    }

    // Setup the dnd listeners.
    const dropZone = document.getElementById('dicomImage');
    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);


    cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.configure({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Add custom headers here (e.g. auth tokens)
            //xhr.setRequestHeader('x-auth-token', 'my auth token');

        },
        useWebWorkers: true,
    });

    let loaded = false;

    function loadAndViewImage(imageId) {
        const element = document.getElementById('dicomImage');
        const start = new Date().getTime();
        cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(function(image) {
            console.log(image);
            const viewport = cornerstone.getDefaultViewportForImage(element, image);
            cornerstone.displayImage(element, image, viewport);
            if(loaded === false) {
                cornerstoneTools.mouseInput.enable(element);
                cornerstoneTools.mouseWheelInput.enable(element);
                cornerstoneTools.wwwc.activate(element, 1); // ww/wc is the default tool for left mouse button
                cornerstoneTools.pan.activate(element, 2); // pan is the default tool for middle mouse button
                cornerstoneTools.zoom.activate(element, 4); // zoom is the default tool for right mouse button
                cornerstoneTools.zoomWheel.activate(element); // zoom is the default tool for middle mouse wheel

                cornerstoneTools.imageStats.enable(element);
                loaded = true;
            }

            function getTransferSyntax() {
                const value = image.data.string('x00020010');
                return value + ' [' + uids[value] + ']';
            }

            function getSopClass() {
                const value = image.data.string('x00080016');
                return value + ' [' + uids[value] + ']';
            }

            function getPixelRepresentation() {
                const value = image.data.uint16('x00280103');
                if(value === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                return value + (value === 0 ? ' (unsigned)' : ' (signed)');
            }

            function getPlanarConfiguration() {
                const value = image.data.uint16('x00280006');
                if(value === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                return value + (value === 0 ? ' (pixel)' : ' (plane)');
            }

            document.getElementById('transferSyntax').textContent = getTransferSyntax();
            document.getElementById('sopClass').textContent = getSopClass();
            document.getElementById('samplesPerPixel').textContent = image.data.uint16('x00280002');
            document.getElementById('photometricInterpretation').textContent = image.data.string('x00280004');
            document.getElementById('numberOfFrames').textContent = image.data.string('x00280008');
            document.getElementById('planarConfiguration').textContent = getPlanarConfiguration();
            document.getElementById('rows').textContent = image.data.uint16('x00280010');
            document.getElementById('columns').textContent = image.data.uint16('x00280011');
            document.getElementById('pixelSpacing').textContent = image.data.string('x00280030');
            document.getElementById('bitsAllocated').textContent = image.data.uint16('x00280100');
            document.getElementById('bitsStored').textContent = image.data.uint16('x00280101');
            document.getElementById('highBit').textContent = image.data.uint16('x00280102');
            document.getElementById('pixelRepresentation').textContent = getPixelRepresentation();
            document.getElementById('windowCenter').textContent = image.data.string('x00281050');
            document.getElementById('windowWidth').textContent = image.data.string('x00281051');
            document.getElementById('rescaleIntercept').textContent = image.data.string('x00281052');
            document.getElementById('rescaleSlope').textContent = image.data.string('x00281053');
            document.getElementById('basicOffsetTable').textContent = image.data.elements.x7fe00010 && image.data.elements.x7fe00010.basicOffsetTable ? image.data.elements.x7fe00010.basicOffsetTable.length : '';
            document.getElementById('fragments').textContent = image.data.elements.x7fe00010 && image.data.elements.x7fe00010.fragments ? image.data.elements.x7fe00010.fragments.length : '';
            document.getElementById('minStoredPixelValue').textContent = image.minPixelValue;
            document.getElementById('maxStoredPixelValue').textContent = image.maxPixelValue;
            const end = new Date().getTime();
            const time = end - start;
            document.getElementById('totalTime').textContent = time + "ms";
            document.getElementById('loadTime').textContent = image.loadTimeInMS + "ms";
            document.getElementById('decodeTime').textContent = image.decodeTimeInMS + "ms";

        }, function(err) {
            alert(err);
        });
    }

    cornerstone.events.addEventListener('cornerstoneimageloadprogress', function(event) {
        const eventData = event.detail;
        const loadProgress = document.getElementById('loadProgress');
        loadProgress.textContent = `Image Load Progress: ${eventData.percentComplete}%`;
    });

    const element = document.getElementById('dicomImage');
    cornerstone.enable(element);

    document.getElementById('selectFile').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        // Add the file to the cornerstoneFileImageLoader and get unique
        // number for that file
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const imageId = cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.wadouri.fileManager.add(file);
        loadAndViewImage(imageId);
    });





</script>
</html>
```

Comment: How about adding some code here?

Comment: @PowerStat  code